# Custom cursor not loading on slideshow fade

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using RoyalSlider plugin to create slideshows on on [this site](http://www.whateveritscalled.com/2015/10/06/project-1/)

I have the following javascript to create the two fields that overlay the slideshows, to allow for left and right click navigation. The problem is that the custom cursor doesn't stay loaded during the fade transition between slides. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Many thanks,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.royalSlider').each(function() {
        var slider = $(this);
        var sliderInstance = slider.data('royalSlider');

        if(sliderInstance) {
            var slideCounter = $('<div class="rsSlideCount"></div>').appendTo( slider );

            var updCount = function () {
                slideCounter.html( (sliderInstance.currSlideId+1) + ' / ' + sliderInstance.numSlides );
            }
            sliderInstance.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', updCount);
            updCount();     
        }

        slider.append('<div class="rs-prev"/>');
        slider.append('<div class="rs-next"/>');
        slider.find('.rs-prev').click(function() {
            slider.royalSlider('prev');
        });
        slider.find('.rs-next').click(function() {
            slider.royalSlider('next');
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this into your CSS:

```
div.rs-prev,
div.rs-next {
    z-index: 10;
}
```

This worked for me.